# How to change IP Address of remote VM with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.0

I am creating an auto-build process in Powershell and need to build a VM with a static IP address. The VM gets built by the script and is assigned a DHCP IP Address. I can query the Hyper-V host to get the IP Address of the newly created VM with `Get-NetAdapter` so that I can remote to it with `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ip_address>`. All good so far. The next line in my powershell script then changes the IP address of the remote VM with `New-NetIPAddress` but the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet then times out after 4 minutes.

My question is, is there a better way to change the IP remotely? Can I set a timeout and handle it gracefully somehow? At the moment it sits there for 4 mins and then gives a connection error.

**EDIT**: If I change the IpAddress in a job as suggested by Gerald, how would I pass parameters into the job? My current code for changing the IP looks like:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TempIpAddress -Credential $cred -scriptblock {param ($IpAddress, $DefaultGateway) Get-NetIpAddress | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceAlias -match "Ethernet" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"} | New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress $IpAddress –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $DefaultGateway} -ArgumentList $NewIpAddress, $DefaultGateway`

**EDIT2**: I tried this, the job gets created but doesn't do anything. And when I run `Get-Job` nothing gets returned.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TempIpAddress -Credential $cred -scriptblock {Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param ($IpAddress, $DefaultGateway) Get-NetIpAddress | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceAlias -match "Ethernet" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"} | New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress $IpAddress –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $DefaultGateway} -ArgumentList $NewIpAddress, $DefaultGateway}`

Comment: It will timeout, the machine you connected to is no longer on the IP address you connected to. You need to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <inew_p_address>` after changing it

Comment: @Drifter104 thanks yes I am aware of that. That's not my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently not able to test this, but soemthing like this should work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ip_address> -ScriptBlock { Start-Job -ScriptBlock { New-NetIPAddress ... } }
```

This should start the cmdlet in the background, allowing you to disconnect gracefully. You should then run the next commands on the new ip address.

Comment: Still not *that* graceful! My next line of code would have to ping the new ip and then carry on when a response is received. A bit messy, but doable. Any other thoughts? :)

Comment: Well, you can do a sleep for a couple of seconds before the next command. Personally I'd ping the new ip until it is accessible.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald Schneider , I just edited my question because I need to pass params in. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: I did it by using -AsJob instead of Start-Job